# Why dropdown is not popping up on clicking the toggle button in navbar in handlebar?

Tags: bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, handlebars.js, html-lists, logout

Below is the handlebar code using bootstrap I am trying to load the drop-down options for the user to logout. But when I click the username that is "Vikas" the dropdown menu options of logout doesn't popup. What changes do i need to do in the code?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                      role = "button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                      "Vikas"<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Did you write (or import) Bootstrap scripts?

Comment: its  working in codepen but in y browser its not working i dont know.

Comment: Check if you are getting any error in console?